# Created doctype is not showing in Frappe/ERPNext

Tags: frappe

I have created a custom doctype in ERPNext v10^, but the problem is; created doctype shows in doctype list but it's related form doesn't exist.

ERPNext is in production mode and the option 'custom' is by default checked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have probably restricted it to a specific domain. Remove that limitations and try again.

[Restrict to Domain should be empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV0Nu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is related permissions. Please check the user you are accessing with has the requisite permissions for the DocType.